# draw shape inside a panel by relative positioning

Tags: java, graphics

I need to draw some shapes randomly inside a panel but with relative positioning to this specific panel not to the frame.

```
public class myFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

int x_pos;
int y_pos;
int scope = 20;

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    x_pos = (int) (Math.random() * 1000) % panel.getWidth();
    y_pos = (int) (Math.random() * 1000) % panel.getHeight();

    //===== NODE
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    fillCircle(g , x_pos, y_pos, 10);

    //===== SCOPE
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    drawCircle(g , x_pos, y_pos, scope);
}

public void fillCircle(Graphics g, int x, int y, int r){
    x = x - (r/2);
    y = y - (r/2);
    g.fillOval(x, y, r, r);
}

public void drawCircle(Graphics g, int x, int y, int r){
    x = x - (r/2);
    y = y - (r/2);
    g.drawOval(x, y, r, r);
}
}
```

but the node is drawn outside because the panel is not set at (0,0) in the frame, how to let the panel the unique reference because I need to set a mobility to different nodes randomly.

Thanks

Comment: Okay, then don't override `paint` of a top level container (this is a general recommendation) and override the `paintComponent` method of the panel you need to paint relative to, then when `paintComponent` is called, the coordinate system will have been translated to the context of the panel (0x0 will be the top left corner of the panel)

Comment: I tried to, but when changing inheritance to JPanel instead of JFrame, it causes many problems

Comment: Well, it would solve your question, prevent you from accidentally painting under the frame boards or components from painting themselves independently of the frame's paint cycle

Comment: thank you @MadProgrammer